# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, h2

I am trying to develop my first JSF app using hibernate4 + spring3 + H2 database but I am having this problem.

```
type Exception report

message Cant instantiate class: view.managed.FiloMB.

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Cant instantiate class: view.managed.FiloMB.
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)

root cause

com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Cant instantiate class: view.managed.FiloMB.
    com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:193)
    com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:102)
    com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:408)
    com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:268)
    com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244)
    com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116)
    com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:72)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:161)
    org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:169)
    org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.getValueToRender(ComponentUtils.java:64)
    org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputTextRenderer.encodeMarkup(InputTextRenderer.java:77)
    org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputTextRenderer.encodeEnd(InputTextRenderer.java:51)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:312)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
    javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:304)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:309)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:304)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:437)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:124)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)

root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [sets/spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cache/CacheProvider
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:532)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:608)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    sets.SpringFactory.getInstance(SpringFactory.java:11)
    control.Control.<init>(Control.java:19)
    view.managed.MB.<init>(MB.java:21)
    view.managed.FiloMB.<init>(FiloMB.java:22)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:374)
    java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:327)
    com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:188)
    com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:102)
    com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:408)
    com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:268)
    com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244)
    com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116)
    com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:72)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:161)
    org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:169)
    org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.getValueToRender(ComponentUtils.java:64)
    org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputTextRenderer.encodeMarkup(InputTextRenderer.java:77)
    org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputTextRenderer.encodeEnd(InputTextRenderer.java:51)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:312)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
    javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:304)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:309)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:304)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:437)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:124)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)

root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cache/CacheProvider
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2451)
    java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2571)
    java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2587)
    java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1429)
    org.springframework.beans.ExtendedBeanInfoFactory.supports(ExtendedBeanInfoFactory.java:53)
    org.springframework.beans.ExtendedBeanInfoFactory.getBeanInfo(ExtendedBeanInfoFactory.java:44)
    org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.<init>(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:236)
    org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.forClass(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:152)
    org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getCachedIntrospectionResults(BeanWrapperImpl.java:321)
    org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyDescriptorInternal(BeanWrapperImpl.java:351)
    org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.isWritableProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:427)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1393)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1132)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:608)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    sets.SpringFactory.getInstance(SpringFactory.java:11)
    control.Control.<init>(Control.java:19)
    view.managed.MB.<init>(MB.java:21)
    view.managed.FiloMB.<init>(FiloMB.java:22)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:374)
    java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:327)
    com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:188)
    com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:102)
    com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:408)
    com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:268)
    com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244)
    com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116)
    com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:72)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:161)
    org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:169)
    org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.getValueToRender(ComponentUtils.java:64)
    org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputTextRenderer.encodeMarkup(InputTextRenderer.java:77)
    org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputTextRenderer.encodeEnd(InputTextRenderer.java:51)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:312)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
    javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:304)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:309)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:304)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:437)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:124)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)

root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cache.CacheProvider
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2451)
    java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2571)
    java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2587)
    java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1429)
    org.springframework.beans.ExtendedBeanInfoFactory.supports(ExtendedBeanInfoFactory.java:53)
    org.springframework.beans.ExtendedBeanInfoFactory.getBeanInfo(ExtendedBeanInfoFactory.java:44)
    org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.<init>(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:236)
    org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.forClass(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:152)
    org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getCachedIntrospectionResults(BeanWrapperImpl.java:321)
    org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyDescriptorInternal(BeanWrapperImpl.java:351)
    org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.isWritableProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:427)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1393)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1132)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:608)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    sets.SpringFactory.getInstance(SpringFactory.java:11)
    control.Control.<init>(Control.java:19)
    view.managed.MB.<init>(MB.java:21)
    view.managed.FiloMB.<init>(FiloMB.java:22)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:374)
    java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:327)
    com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:188)
    com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:102)
    com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:408)
    com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:268)
    com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244)
    com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116)
    com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:72)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:161)
    org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:169)
    org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.getValueToRender(ComponentUtils.java:64)
    org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputTextRenderer.encodeMarkup(InputTextRenderer.java:77)
    org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputTextRenderer.encodeEnd(InputTextRenderer.java:51)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:312)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
    javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:304)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:309)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:304)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:437)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:124)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.35 logs.
```

this is my spring.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Conexão com banco de dados -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="sets.Connect" />
    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>model.Reino</value>
                <value>model.Filo</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
    <!-- Injeta uma sessão do hibernate -->
    <bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <!-- DAOs -->
    <bean id="genericDAO" class="persistence.GenericDAO">
        <!-- Injeta esse objeto hibernateTemplate dentro do DAO -->
        <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Try using `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean` instead of `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean`

Answer (score 1):

class="org.springframework.orm.**hibernate3**.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"

But you are using hibernate4?

Might want to check that configuration.